# PictureBox not updating on label clicked

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I've created this program in C++-cli Visual Studio to update a picturebox on a label click but it doesn't get updated.

```
private: System::Void label1_Click2(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (ctapas==1)
            pictureBox14->ImageLocation = "./Release/IMG/420.png";
        if (ctapas==2)
            pictureBox14->ImageLocation = "./Release/IMG/421.png";
    ctapas++;
```

Comment: `label1_Click2` => are you sure that this is the event handler that is wired to the event?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that